# Error on Multiplication three float value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I want to multiply three `varchar` columns with converting to float, I get

> Error Converting data type varchar to float

error message from SQL Server.

I use `isnumeric` and round function in my script too but I receive error too

Comment: If those are numerical values - ***WHY OH WHY*** are they stored as `varchar` then?!?!?!?!?! [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: Please add your code (ddl and select) and example data.

Comment: I can't change data type,It's Customer's table

Comment: my problem solved, one of my three columns came from a view that converted to float there and i converted that again.when i remove second convert, my problem solved.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of dot in your varchar which the sql server can't convert it .

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use varchar variables then you have to cast the value before multiplying it.
use cast or convert functions.

```
select cast (@your_variable_or_column_here as float)
```

if the point character is an issue, use a replace :

```
select cast (replace(@your_variable_or_column_here,'.',',') as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    TRY_CAST(column1 AS float)
    * TRY_CAST(column2 AS float)
    * TRY_CAST(column3 AS float) AS result
FROM
    your_table;
```

Comment: This just ignores the problem, since you just get NULLs if cast fails

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.